About Pennylane's QCNN Tutorial
Excuse me for the basic question.
pennylane tutorial includes the following
「Since we are not going to train the quantum convolution layer, it is more efficient to apply it as a “pre-processing”」
It is my understanding that quantum machine learning generally involves adjusting and learning the amount of rotation of the rotation gate of a quantum circuit.
What is the reason for not train the quantum convolution layer and not adjusted rotation gate this time?
https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_quanvolution/

I see the pennylane demo to be following the paper they are inspired from. There is a Note in that demo which has the answer to your question that quotes:

Note:
In this tutorial we follow the approach of Ref. [1] in which a
fixed non-trainable quantum circuit is used as a “quanvolution”
kernel, while the subsequent classical layers are trained for the
classification problem of interest. However, by leveraging the ability
of PennyLane to evaluate gradients of quantum circuits, the quantum
kernel could also be trained.

As you can understand from this, you could potentially train the parameterized circuit. But in that tutorial, they are using the circuit as a feature extractor only.
